# detect when sssd connects to the ladp server and finds a specific group in boot

Tags: ldap, systemd, sssd, udev, udevd

I am looking to find a way so when system is booting , i can detect when sssd connect to LDAP server and finds a specific group then reload the systemd-udevd.
i actually want to automate all of these steps.
does any one have any idea?